# Tools to find bottlenecks in hardware configuration

Tags: laptop, performance, upgrade

I'm thinking of upgrading my notebook and I want to find the tightest bottlenecks in its hardware configuration to target my money in the most efficient way. So what software tool can you recommend to perform such analysis?

Comment: But it's generally difficult to upgrade notebooks, except for the memory or the hard drive. See this question for some suggestions: http://superuser.com/questions/24945/speed-up-a-laptop-with-an-additional-device

Comment: agreed, more memory and a hard disk with with larger cache memory and higher spin rate, that's pretty much all there is to upgrade in a notebook. or a get a decent solid state disk for a real performance boost and greatly improved robustness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Vista the built in Reliability and Performance Monitoring Tool would give you good feedback on bottlenecks.  See [Jeffs post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001235.html) on this tool.

Comment: Yes I use Vista and that's a very good solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off getting a new notebook in some cases .. Memory and Hard Drive are usually the 2 easily replaceable components in a notebook. If you're thinking of replacing the processor or the mainboard, it'd be better to ebay your notebook and pour that cash towards a new notebook. Newer notebooks with good configs are available in the region of 500-600$ nowadays ...

As far as the software goes, you can run a diagnostics check up using the bios or use something like SiSoft Sandra ..